# How to pass array length to another component (from child to parent component) in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have two components Dashboard.vue(parent) and DisplayBooks.vue(child). inside child component i have one array addedBooks:[] it should be incremented when user clicks on ADD TO BAG button and decremented when user clicks on ADDED TO BAG button  upto this it's working fine ,Now hat my requirement is addedBooks.length (array length)should be transferred from DisplayBooks.vue to the Dashboard.vue component.how to acheive this thing please help me

`Dashboard.vue`

```
<template>
<div class="main">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <img src="../assets/education.png" alt="notFound" class="education-image" />
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
                <p class="brand">Bookstore</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="input-group">
            <i @click="handlesubmit();" class="fas fa-search"></i>
            <div class="form-outline">
                <input type="search" v-model="name" class="form-control" placeholder='search...' />
            </div>
        </div>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="right-bar">
            <li><a> <i class="far fa-user"></i></a></li>
            <p class="profile-content">profile</p>
<!-- here i want to display the array length -->
            <li><a><i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i></a></li>
            <p class="cart-content">cart</p>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="mid-body">
        <h6>Books<span class="items">(128items)</span></h6>

        <select class="options" @change="applyOption">
            <option disabled value="">Sort by relevance</option>
            <option value="HighToLow">price:High to Low</option>
            <option value="LowToHigh">price:Low to High</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div v-if="flam==false">
        <h2>Hello</h2>
    </div>

    <DisplayBooks v-show="flag==='noOrder'" />
    <sortBooksLowtoHigh v-show="flag==='lowToHigh'" />
    <sortBooksHightoLow v-show="flag==='highToLow'" />
</div>
</template>

<script>
import sortBooksLowtoHigh from './sortBooksLowtoHigh.vue'
import sortBooksHightoLow from './sortBooksHightoLow.vue'
import DisplayBooks from './DisplayBooks.vue'
export default {
    components: {
        DisplayBooks,
        sortBooksLowtoHigh,
        sortBooksHightoLow
    },
    data() {
        return {
            flag: 'noOrder',
            brand: 'Bookstore',
            name: '',
            flam: true,
            visible: true,
            books: [{

            }]
        }
    },
    methods: {

        flip() {
            this.flam = !this.flam;
        },

        applyOption(evt) {
            if (evt.target.value === "HighToLow") {
                this.flag = 'highToLow';
            } else this.flag = 'lowToHigh';
        },
      
    }

}
</script>
```

`DisplayBooks.vue`

```
<template>
<div class="carddisplay-section">
    <div v-for="book in books" :key="book.id" class="card book">
        <div class="image-section">
            <div class="image-container">
                <img  v-bind:src="book.file" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="title-section">
            {{book.name}}
        </div>
        <div class="author-section">
            by {{book.author}}
        </div>
        <div class="price-section">
            Rs. {{book.price}}<label class="default">(2000)</label>
            <button v-if="flag" class="btn-grp" type="submit" @click="handlesubmit();Togglebtn();">close</button>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <div class="button-groups"  v-if="!addedBooks.includes(book.id)">
                <button type="submit"  @click="handleCart(book.id);toggle(book.id);addedBooks.push(book.id)"  class="AddBag">Add to Bag</button>
                <button  class="wishlist">wishlist</button>
            </div>
            <div class="AddedBag" v-else>
            <button class="big-btn" @click="removeFromCart(book.id);addedBooks=addedBooks.filter(id=>id!==book.id)">Added to Bag</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import service from '../service/User'
export default {
    data() {
        return {
           
            flag: true,
            state: true,
            addedBooks:[], // this array length should be passed to dashboard component
            clickedCard: '',
            books: [{
                id: 0,
                file: 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41MdP5Tn0wL._SX258_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg',
                name: 'Dont Make me think',
                author: 'Sai',
                price: '1500'
            }, ]
        }
    },
    methods: {
     
        flip() {
            this.state = !this.state;
        },
        Togglebtn() {
            this.flag = !this.flag;
        },
        handlesubmit() {
            service.userDisplayBooks().then(response => {  
                this.books.push(...response.data);  
            })
        },
        handleCart(bookId){
            let userData={
                id: bookId,
            }
            service.userUpdateCart(userData).then(response=>{
                return response;
            })
        },
        removeFromCart(bookId){
            let userData={
                id:bookId,
            }
            service.userRemoveFromCart(userData).then(response=>{
                return response;
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: from child to parent one usually `emit`s from child and has an event listener on the parent - alternatively, if you use vuex, you could do it through there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watch the array change and emit its length to the parent :

**DisplayBooks.vue**

```
    data() {
        return {
           
            flag: true,
            state: true,
            addedBooks:[], // this array length should be passed to dashboard component
            clickedCard: '',
            books: [{
                id: 0,
                file: 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41MdP5Tn0wL._SX258_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg',
                name: 'Dont Make me think',
                author: 'Sai',
                price: '1500'
            }, ]
        }
    },
watch:{
    addedBooks:{
            handler(val){
               this.$emit('update-books-count',val.length)
             },
             deep:true
          }

}
```

**Dashboard**

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="right-bar">
            <li><a> <i class="far fa-user"></i></a></li>
            <p class="profile-content">profile</p>
            <p>{{booksCount}}</p>
            <li><a><i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i></a></li>
            <p class="cart-content">cart</p>
        </ul>
...
 <DisplayBooks v-show="flag==='noOrder'" @update-books-count="(n)=>booksCount=n"/>
...
  data() {
        return {
            booksCount:0,
            flag: 'noOrder',
            brand: 'Bookstore',
            name: '',
            flam: true,
            visible: true,
            books: [{

            }]
        }
    },
```

Comment: it's working fine but if the count is zero means i want to hide and if the count is greater than zero then only it should be visibile  like that i want to display is it possible to develop

Comment: Try out `<p v-if="booksCount">{{booksCount}}</p>`

Comment: Thank you @Boussadjra Brahim, it's working fine. can you please provide some good reference for emit watcher things

Comment: you could find more about this stuff in official docs